# I am not able to compile Instance id for Google Play Services

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services

I am trying to add the Instance Id (last line)

```
dependencies {
   //Basic Google libs
   compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.5.0'
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.5.0'
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.5.0'
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.5.0'
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:7.5.0'
   compile 'com.google.android.gms.iid:7.5.0'
}
```

but I keep getting:

> Error:Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms.iid:7.5.0:

Any clue why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing like : 'com.google.android.gms.iid:7.5.0' provided by google play services

If you are looking for identity service then it should be :

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:7.5.0
```

Refer link : https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: yep, i am dumb. i had a brain fart. that was the package name

Comment: Thanks. I simply deleted nonexisten "com.google.android.gms:play-services-iid" (and retained "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm").

Answer (score 5):

Not sure for version 7.5 
but for 10.0.1 just use

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-iid:10.0.1'
```

Answer (score 2):

For everyone searching for `InstanceId` for the new GCM, Firebase Cloud Messaging, use FirebaseInstanceId instead. With:

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
```

read more at https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-register